# Javascript code inside click event is executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('selector').on('click', 'target', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('span').empty();
    $('span2').append('something');
});
```

The last line is executed twice, why does this happen?

Comment: You have an element `<span2></span2>` ? If you've changed this from what it actually is, it might help if you show your actual selector, as this might be where the error lies

Comment: The actual selector is the form where the target and spans are included.

Comment: @Curt - I hope that's just an attempt to simplify the code -- otherwise the answer probably has something to do with the semantics of the <selector> element.

Comment: Are you listening for another click event somewhere which might bubble up here?

Answer (score -1):

What is target here

```
'target'
```

It is supposed to be

```
'#target'   // If ID

'.target'  // If Class
```

Looks like you are not selecting the right selectors..

Same with these 2 selectors  `$('selector')   $('span2')`

Comment: I'd bet these were obfuscations made by the OP, not actual code.

Comment: @user1704416 If you are going to obfuscate, you need to do it in such a way as to not cause this type of confusion.

Comment: Provide the HTML so that I will be easy to explain